# Рекурсия в Excel

Tags: excel

Как посчитать в Excel x=x+15% и так заданное количество раз.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С учетом последнего комментария [[@mikelsv](/users/2575/mikelsv)](/users/2575/mikelsv), задачу следует сформулировать так:

```
у=x+15%=x*1.15
```

А если "заданное количество раз", то

```
y=x*k^n
```

где k - коэффициент, n - "заданное количество раз".

В Excel есть функция СТЕПЕНЬ. Если A1, B1 и C1 - это x, k и n, то в D1 запишем

```
=A1*СТЕПЕНЬ(B1;C1)
```

Comment: Всего-то :)
Немного напильником:
=A1*B1^C1

Comment: @vikttur, да, согласен, это я немного усложнил :)

Comment: И до меня сразу не дошло, что можно использовать степень. (

Answer (score -1):

Циклом?

```
Sub cycle_()
Dim iVal As Double, n As Long
Dim i As Long
    iVal = 5 ' значение х
    n = 20 ' количество

    For i = 1 To n
        iVal = iVal * 1.15
    Next i

    MsgBox iVal
End Sub
```

Comment: Мне нужно взять данные из двух ячеек и получить результат в третьей. Нет уже готовых формул?